# React Native ToDo App not properly displaying inputted text

Tags: react-native

My todo app is functioning for the most part but whenever I try to type something into add to the todo list, displays the date twice instead of the written text. Here's an example picture. I try to put in hello and press the button.

[image]

Here is also the github for the project: 
https://github.com/Accurac/todoApp2018/tree/master/todoApp

The main files to consider are App.js -- app/components/main.js -- app/components/note.js

Thank you in advance for helping me, I'm quite a novice at this

Answer (score 0):

You have two Text components that display date.

```
export default class Note extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View key={this.props.keyval} style={styles.note}>
        <Text style={styles.noteText}>{this.props.val.date}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.noteText}>{this.props.val.date}</Text>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.deleteMethod} style={styles.noteDelete}>
          <Text style={styles.noteDeleteText}>D</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

You probably want this

```
<Text style={styles.noteText}>{this.props.val.date}</Text>
<Text style={styles.noteText}>{this.props.val.note}</Text>
```

Also I apologize if this comes off as rude, but in the future please include code snippets for your questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked out, and I will keep that in mind in the future!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, can you mark my answer as the correct one please?